# How to convert this recursive solution to memoized solution for longest common substring problem?

Tags: string, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

I was able to come up with the recursive solution to the longest common substring problem on my own:

```java
import static java.lang.Math.max;

public class SolutionRecursive {
    public int longestCommonSubstringLength(String X, String Y) {
        return lcsHelper(X, Y, 1, 1, 0);
    }

    private int lcsHelper(String X, String Y, int xSize, int ySize, int runningSubstringSize) {
        if (xSize > X.length() || ySize > Y.length()) return runningSubstringSize;
        if (X.charAt(xSize - 1) != Y.charAt(ySize - 1)) {
            return max(runningSubstringSize,
                    max(lcsHelper(X, Y, xSize + 1, ySize, 0),
                            lcsHelper(X, Y, xSize, ySize + 1, 0)));
        }
        return lcsHelper(X, Y, xSize + 1, ySize + 1, runningSubstringSize + 1);
    }
}
```

I tested it and it seems to work fine but I am having trouble memoizing the recursive calls.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SolutionMemoized implements SolutionLCS{
    private final int UNFILLED = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    public int longestCommonSubstringLength(String X, String Y) {
        int[][][] memo = new int[X.length() + 1][Y.length() + 1][X.length() + 1];
        for (int i = 1; i < X.length() + 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Y.length() + 1; j++) {
                Arrays.fill(memo[i][j], UNFILLED);
            }
        }
        int lcs = lcsHelper(X, Y, X.length(), Y.length(), memo, 0);
        return lcs;
    }

    private int lcsHelper(String X, String Y, int xSize, int ySize, int[][][] memo, int runningSubstringSize) {
        if (xSize == 0 || ySize == 0) {
            return runningSubstringSize;
        }
        if (memo[xSize][ySize][runningSubstringSize] != UNFILLED) {
            return memo[xSize][ySize][runningSubstringSize];
        }
        if (X.charAt(xSize - 1) == Y.charAt(ySize - 1)) {
            memo[xSize][ySize][runningSubstringSize] = lcsHelper(X, Y, xSize - 1, ySize - 1, memo,
                    runningSubstringSize + 1);
        } else {
            memo[xSize][ySize][runningSubstringSize] = Math.max(runningSubstringSize,
                    Math.max(
                            lcsHelper(X, Y, xSize - 1, ySize, memo, 0),
                            lcsHelper(X, Y, xSize, ySize - 1, memo, 0)
                    ));
        }
        return memo[xSize][ySize][runningSubstringSize];
    }
}
```

This apparently fails for `longestCommonSubstringLength("KXCGMTMVVGFQQWSPD","JXZADDUKVLQPKUZJZHWSUTPCAFSYAIBJHAMMEGWBTPQELRNKBLDXGUZGCSEC")` for which the required answer is 2 but it gives 1. I couldn't find lower length failed tests.

Could anyone tell me why it doesn't work? I feel like there is clear 1-1 correspondence between my recursive and memoized codes.

On [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lj90FqNCIJE&t=578s) I found a fix but the author didn't explain how he arrived at it. The fix is changing my last few lines of code to:

```java
  int s1 = runningSubstringSize;

        if (X.charAt(xSize - 1) == Y.charAt(ySize - 1)) {
            s1 = lcsHelper(X, Y, xSize - 1, ySize - 1, memo,
                    runningSubstringSize + 1);
        }
        int s2 = Math.max(runningSubstringSize,
                Math.max(
                        lcsHelper(X, Y, xSize - 1, ySize, memo, 0),
                        lcsHelper(X, Y, xSize, ySize - 1, memo, 0)
                ));

        return memo[xSize][ySize][runningSubstringSize] = Math.max(s1, s2);
```

Why doesn't my solution (code block 2) work even though there seems to be 1-1 correspondence between it and the recursive code? And how is the fix correcting it?

Comment: Have you tried using a smaller input and checking where does the memoization table go wrong?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Yeah, it works for (X="ABE", Y="AB") but does not work for (X= "AB",Y="ABE") but I can't see what's wrong with my recurrences.

Comment: Try printing the memoized table, and compare it with a dry run of the approach

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I needed to add a 3rd dimension for 1-1 correspondence between my recursive and memoized codes. Now the code seems to work all the small length strings but fails for the particular case I updated in my question.

Comment: You end your question with a fix. This makes your question foggy. Can you please be clear in your question what you are asking?

Comment: @trincot Why doesn't my solution (code block 2) work? And how is the fix correcting it?

Answer (score 0):

The fix you've added has made the issue evident:

If the current characters are equal, you greedily increase the `runningSubstringSize` and recurse for the smaller strings. Example: `solution for (ABDC, AFC) reduced to solution for (ABD, AF) + 1`.

However, you're not considering the "normal" scenario/flow of reducing only one string and checking if it gives a better solution. From the previous example, it should ideally be

```
solution(ABDC, AFC) = max (
    solution(ABD, AFC),
    solution(ABDC, AF),
    solution(ABD, AF) + 1
)
```

The added fix does exactly that; it compares all scenarios before setting the updated value in the memoization table.

Comment: If that was the problem then how did it work for the recursive version?

Comment: @learner in the recursive version, you're calculating the value each time. In the memoized version, you're incorrectly storing the value in the DP table, which is returned if further sub-calls